# ASP.NET Core MVC autocomplete partial view not showing result

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a partial view that will not show the result that it gets from the controller. This is in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1.

The base for the code is from [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-AutoComplete-from-Database-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx).

Here is the partial view:

```
@model City

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Grad</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-controller="City" id="TestForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" id="CityName" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
                        <input asp-for="PostalCode" class="form-control" id="PostalCode" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Country TEST</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtCounty" name="CountyName"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hfCountry" name="CountyID" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="CountryID" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="SaveCity" />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="CloseCity" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The part in question is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Country TEST</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtCounty" name="CountyName"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfCountry" name="CountyID" />
    <span asp-validation-for="CountryID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

It does not want to show the result it [gets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTWG8.png).

The jQuery method I use is, it is inside the Index.cshtml scripts:

```
$(document).on("focus", "#txtCountry", function (e) {
    $("#txtCountry").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/City/AutoComplete/',
                type: "POST",
                data: { "prefix": request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#hfCountry").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

When I put this code:

```
<input type="text" id="txtCounty" name="CountyName"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hfCountry" name="CountyID" />
```

outside the partial view it [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZOAy.png) the searched for thing.

Here is controller for it:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
    {

        var countries = (from country in this._dbContext.Countries
                        where country.Name.ToLower().Contains(prefix.ToLower())
                        select new
                        {
                            label = country.Name,
                            val = country.ID
                        }).ToList();
   return Json(countries); 
}
```

Can anybody help I just can not find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
The text was showing behind the modal, that is way I could not see it.

```
    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete {
            z-index: 5000;
        }
    </style>
```

Put that inside the _Layout.cshtml file, inside the enviroment.

```
<environment include="Development">
    ... some stuff...    

    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete {
            z-index: 5000;
        }
    </style>

     ... some ,oe stuff...    
</environment>
```